# Integration by parts or substitution

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, substitution

> Let $ f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a derivative function
> with continue derivative so that $f(a)=0$ and $f(b)=6$.  Let $g(x)$
> also be $g(x)=\int_{6}^{f(x)} \sqrt[4]{1+t^{2}} dt $
>
> Then, the value of $ \int_{a}^{b} f'(x) g(x) dx$ is ...

I am having a hard time with this question... I tried using integration by parts using:
$u=g(x)$  and $dv=f'(x)$
so that
$$\int_{a}^{b} f'(x) g(x) dx = g(x) f(x) - \int_{a}^{b} f(x)g'(x)$$

Then
$$\int_{a}^{b} f'(x) g(x) dx = \int_{6}^{f(x)}\sqrt[4]{1+t^{2}}dt f(x) - \int_{a}^{b} f(x)\sqrt[4]{1+t^{2}}dt$$

*I'm not supposed to use Fubini's theorem*, so I'm trying to solve it with integration by parts or with substitution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\int_a^b f'(x) g(x)dx &= \left[f(x) g(x)\right]_a^b-\int_a^b f(x) g'(x)dx\\
& = f(b)g(b)-f(a)g(a)-\int_a^b f(x)f'(x)\sqrt[4]{1+f(x)^2}\\
&= f(b)\underbrace{g(b)}_{=0}-\underbrace{f(a)}_{=0}g(a) -\frac 12 \left[ \frac{(1+f(x)^2)^{5/4}}{5/4}\right]_a^b\\
& = -\frac 25 (37^{5/4}-1) 
\end{align*}

Comment: Sorry, I actually miswrote the lower limit of the integer, it is not 0, but 6, what makes finding the g(b) easier (it is 0) , and now g(a) is the problem

Comment: @kimpetras The situation is actually much better now because $g(a)$ appears multiplied by $f(a)$, which is zero...